# NiFi ListAzureBlobStorage with HTTP proxy with Authentication

Tags: apache-nifi, http-proxy, azure-blob-storage

We are using NiFi to collect files from Azure Blob Storage and are sitting behind a forward HTTP Proxy. Our organization is tightening the security and now all traffic through the proxy needs to be authenticated. The ListAzureBlobStorage processor does not support it. Is there a way around it?

Answer (score 0):

@Peter Zandbergen  You did not share your NiFI Version, but in my local NiFI (1.9) there is Proxy Configuration Service available in the ListAzureBlobStorage Processor.   I would recommend 1.9+ to get the best bug fixes and processors.

If this version is not possible,  it is possible to put newer version NARs into older version of NiFi.  This poses additional issues, but is a viable solution for some scenarios.

Comment: Hi Steven, we are using 1.9.2. Indeed it allows you to attach a proxy configuration service. But as soon as you specify a user name and password for the proxy, then the processor shows a warning that Azure Blob Store does not work with a HTTP proxy with credentials. We managed a workaround with allowing our NiFi server to go through the proxy without authentication, but this is not desired.

Comment: @PeterZandbergen  are you saying you can't use the proxy as HTTP; that its requiring HTTPS?   Have you experimented with the controller service configs to see if can get around it?

Comment: we managed a deal with the IT Network boys to allow us to go through the proxy without authentication. The is not HTTP but the combination of HTTP with authentication that the processor does not like.